# Not getting Sitecore Rocks option to install in Extensions and Updates in VS Ultimate 2012

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2, sitecore-rocks

Trying to install Sitecore Rocks in VS Ultimate 2012 but there is no extension for Sitecore Rocks in extensions and updates option. NuGet Package Manager is only giving three options for Sitecore Rocks :

1.Sitecore Rocks Server (to install sitecore rocks server components assemblies) **version 2.0.0.32**
2.Sitecore.Rocks.Client (to install sitecore rocks client components assemblies) **version 2.0.0.32**
3.Sitecore-Rocks (to install Rocks server components) **version 1.2.6.0**

On installing the above three i am not getting any Sitecore menu option in VS.Please let me know how can i install Sitecore Rocks in VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Rocks is not supported (and afaik, never was supported) on Visual Studio 2012, currently the minimum version Sitecore Rocks integrates with is Visual Studio 2015:

> Sitecore Rocks integrates directly with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and 2017

You can download the plugin for VS 2015/2017 from the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks)

> **Sitecore Rocks no longer supports Visual Studio 2013 as Microsoft has not made the Visual Studio 2013 SDK available on NuGet.**

An older version for VS2013 *used* to be available from AppVeyor, but not that due to their [Retention Policy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#artifacts-retention-policy) anything older than 6 months is no longer available. It is [available on Github](https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/releases/tag/2.0.54) though.

In order to use Sitecore Rocks, you will need to upgrade to VS2013 at a minimum, but suggest moving up to VS2017.